# MVC4 EF5 RedirecttoAction needing a different view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the normal controller with an Index action.

```
public class LotController : Controller
private HouseContext db = new HouseContext();  
public ActionResult Index()
```

In my create action I have used a special view:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? buidID)
{
    var ViewModel = new Lot_create_VM();  // this view only uses dropdown boxes
    ViewBag.HstyleID = new SelectList(db.Hstyles, "HstyleID", "HName"); //populate one here
    //populate more then
    return View();
}
```

The post action works fine, I bring in the viewmodel and transfer those values to the base class and save the changes:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Lot_create_VM lot_create_VM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {  
        Lot lot = new Lot();
        lot.LotName = lot_create_VM.LotName;
    }
    db.Lots.Add(lot);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

with other code here eventually I return to the view Lot_create_VM.

```
    return View(lot_create_VM);
}
```

The problem is that if the create fails (just in and out - no data entered) ModelState.IsValid=false, I try to return to the Index:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Which is expecting view of "Lot" not Lot_create_VM. yielding the following error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MVCBSV.ViewModels.Lot_create_VM', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVCBSV.Models.Lot'"

I've tried:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Lot");
return View("Index", "Lot")
return RedirectToAction("Index",  db = new HouseContext());
```

I can see what is wrong, but cannot see how to change back to the earlier model. Also is this a correct approach when using a ViewModel rather than a Model?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to sleep on it. This changes to model and fixes the problem

```
var ViewModel = new Lot(); 
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```